# How to add Link/ a tag in the options of dropdown in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

So basically, I am working on a project I am not so experienced with REACT,
I want to make a simple dropdown that will change the Url (simple).

**Here is the code-**

```
function Front() {
const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = React.useState("A");



if (selectedOption === "A") {
  //Do something here (but what so that I can put that value of selectedOption in the Url?)
 
} else if (selectedOption === "B") {
  //Do something here

} else if (selectedOption === "C"){
    //Do somthing here
 
}

return (
  
<>

    <div className ="front__text">
       <h1>Wind Pioneers</h1> <button>Tutorial</button>
      
    </div>
    <div className="front__text__second">
        <p>Select System</p>
    <select className="drop"  value={selectedOption}
    onChange={evt => setSelectedOption(evt.target.value)}>
        <option value="A" id={1} >1
        
         </option>
         <option value="B" id={2}>
         2
         </option>
         <option value="C" id={3}>
         3
         </option>
    </select>
    </div>
        

    </div>

   
  
   
 </>
)
}
```

I tried to use  but I think Link and anchor tags not works there as this might consider as bad HTML. What should I need to do to get out of this, plus I don't even want to use any external library to do this.

Comment: If I have understood it correctly, I think you can add an onClick event listener on the button and inside that function access the selectedOption state value and use that to change the url.

Comment: Check This : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58114855/handling-select-options-in-react-hooks

Comment: Do you just want to change the URL and do nothing? Or redirect the page to the URL?

Comment: Actually, I am implementing Dynamic Routing, and if the id (/:id) matches with data's id table will get render, I hope you get  ><   so everything is going fine but right now I have to specify the url manually i want it to be automated :(  I don't even know how to convey XD

Answer (score 1):

You have to install `popper.js` and `jquery.js` using npm.
This will help you:

```
return (
<div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button
      class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle"
      type="button"
      id="dropdownMenuButton"
      data-toggle="dropdown"
      aria-haspopup="true"
      aria-expanded="false"
    >
      Dropdown button
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    {/*enter the url you want inside href atribute*/}
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
        A
      </a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
        B
      </a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
        C
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
);
```